# R: what is the default order of scatter shape in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapes

R `ggplot2` question.

We can get the default color order by `RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n, palette.name)`. How about the order of shapes?

The available shapes in R is [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-point-shapes). I just need the order. I know the first three are `c(16, 17, 15)`, which is circle, triangle and square.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shapes are generated by default by `scales::shape_pal`. By default it only allows for 6 shapes and spits out a warning if you try to go higher. So the default shapes are:

```
> scales::shape_pal()(6)
[1] 16 17 15  3  7  8
```

Or if you want unfilled shapes:

```
> scales::shape_pal(solid=FALSE)(6)
[1] 1 2 0 3 7 8
```

See the example in `example(points)` if you want to see the shapes corresponding to these numbers.